# C++ Vigenere and Caesar cipher in the same programming with switch case

Tags: c++, switch-statement, case

In the first code I did a Caesar cipher and it is working well. However, i cannot added Vigenere. There is a class and some pointers, but they do not work in the `switch`-`case` statement, so I need help.

- encryption part is switch case :3
- decryption part is switch case :4

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
char message[200], ch;
int i, key;
string k,output,messageV;

int menu(int answer);

int main()
{
int answer;
bool keepLooping = true;

while (keepLooping)
{
    cout << "Pick a Choice from the List:  \n(1)Caesar \n(2)Vigenere \n ";
    cin >> answer;

    if (answer == 1)
    {
        while(keepLooping)
         {
         cout << "Pick a Choice from the List:  \n(1)Encryption\n(2)Decryption \n ";
         cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 1)
            {
                answer = 1;
                keepLooping = false ;
            }
            else if(answer == 2)
            {
                answer = 2;
                keepLooping = false;
            }
            else
            {
                keepLooping = true;
            }
         }
    }
    else if(answer == 2) 
    {
        while(keepLooping)
         {
         cout << "Pick a Choice from the List:  \n(1)Encryption\n(2)Decryption \n ";
         cin >> answer;
            if (answer == 1)
            {
                answer = 3;
                keepLooping = false ;
            }
            else if(answer == 2)
            {
                answer = 4;
                keepLooping = false;
            }
            else
            {
                keepLooping = true;
            }
         }
    }
    else
    {
        keepLooping = true;
    }
    
}

menu(answer);
}

int menu(int answer)
{
switch (answer)
{
    case 1://Caesar Cipher Encryption
        cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(message, 200);
        cout << "Enter key: ";
        cin >> key;
        
        for(i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i){
            ch = message[i];
            
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                ch = ch + key;
                
                if(ch > 'z'){
                    ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
                }
                
                message[i] = ch;
            }
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                ch = ch + key;
                
                if(ch > 'Z'){
                    ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
                }
                
                message[i] = ch;
            }
        }
        cout << "Encrypted message: " << message;

        break;

    case 2://Caesar Cipher Decryption
        cout << "Enter a message to decrypt: ";
        cin.ignore();
        cin.getline(message, 200);
        cout << "Enter key: ";
        cin >> key;
        
        for(i = 0; message[i] != '\0'; ++i){
            ch = message[i];
            
            if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                ch = ch - key;
                
                if(ch < 'a'){
                    ch = ch + 'z' - 'a' + 1;
                }
                
                message[i] = ch;
            }
            else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                ch = ch - key;
                
                if(ch > 'a'){
                    ch = ch + 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
                }
                
                message[i] = ch;
            }
        }
        cout << "Decrypted message: " << message;
        
        break;

    case 3:
        cout << "CASE 3";
        break;
    case 4:
        cout << "CASE 4";
        break;

    default:
        cout << "There is no choices." << endl;
}
return answer;
}
```

Vigenere part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Vig {
   public:
      string k;
   Vig(string k) {
      for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); ++i) {
         if (k[i] >= 'A' && k[i] <= 'Z')
            this->k += k[i];
         else if (k[i] >= 'a' && k[i] <= 'z')
            this->k += k[i] + 'A' - 'a';
      }
   }
   string encryption(string t) {
      string output;
      for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < t.length(); ++i) {
         char c = t[i];
         if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            c += 'A' - 'a';
         else if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
            continue;
         output += (c + k[j] - 2 * 'A') % 26 + 'A'; //added 'A' to bring it in range of ASCII alphabet [ 65-90 | A-Z ]
         j = (j + 1) % k.length();
      }
      return output;
   }
   string decryption(string t) {
      string output;
      for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < t.length(); ++i) {
         char c = t[i];
         if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            c += 'A' - 'a';
         else if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
            continue;
         output += (c - k[j] + 26) % 26 + 'A';//added 'A' to bring it in range of ASCII alphabet [ 65-90 | A-Z ]
         j = (j + 1) % k.length();
      }
      return output;
   }
};
int main() {
    char message[200];
    string key;
    cout << "Key: ";
    cin >> key;
    cin.ignore();
    Vig v(key);
    cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
    cin.getline(message, 200);
    string ori = message;
    string encrypt = v.encryption(ori);
    string decrypt = v.decryption(encrypt);
    cout << "Original Message: "<<ori<< endl;
    cout << "Encrypted Message: " << encrypt << endl;
    cout << "Decrypted Message: " << decrypt << endl;
}
```

Comment: You have a `Vig` class, why don't you have a `Caesar` class as well? Once you have a `Caesar` class and can use it in your Caesar cipher program, it should be quite easy to add the `Vig` class to that program and use it.

Comment: There's some other things which looks weird, like `if (answer == 1) { answer = 1; ... }`? Why the assignment?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude there is no need to use class for caesar so keep it like this.
if part for it forces you to choose 1 or 2.

Comment: Could you please clarify how these two pieces of code are related and what specific problems you have encoutered? As far as I can see you don't use `Vic` in the first code. Please be clear about what's wrong with the code.

Comment: @churill I want to put the program using the class into the 1st program. This means that two different chiper methods will work in the same place with a menu. why i must use Vic class for first one ? it is working already. i want to put Encryption and Decryption for first code which are case 3 and case 4.

Comment: @MustafaGüler Ok, fine. And your question is ... ? " What's stopping you from doing this? If you encouter problems please show a [mre] and give us all the details (possibly compiler errors, crash reports, description of expected and actual behaviour).

Comment: why i must use Vic class for first one ? it is working already. i want to put Encryption and Decryption parts from the second code to first code which are case 3 and case 4.

Comment: I want to integrate two different codes and work together. In fact, if you look at the 1st code, there is a menu which people choose the method they want and make encryption. I want to get the processor in the 2nd code to the 1st code so that it works together. Let the two chiper techniques be in one code.

Comment: Even if it's not "needed" it would help to simplify your `menu` function (which is rather badly named since it doesn't really display a menu). It will also help you see the similarities between the two ciphers, both having an `encryption` and a `decryption` function. I also recommend you try to move common code into a function, like the whole input handling in the Caesar `main` function. You have two cases with basically the exact same code, find a way to really make it the same.

Comment: Thats why i need your help bro to find solution.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude they are two different methods so they cannot use the same encryption and descrytion :/

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is that you try to find the common patterns in your two programs. For example you have you have to methods to *encrypt* and *decrypt*. That could be abstracted into two different classes, perhaps with a common base-class defining the interface (allowing things like polymorphism):

```
struct Cipher
{
    virtual std::string encryption(std::string const&) = 0;
    virtual std::string decryption(std::string const&) = 0;
};

class Caesar : public Cipher
{
public:
    std::string encryption(std::string const& s) override
    {
        // TODO: Implement Caesar cipher encryption
    }

    std::string decryption(std::string const& s) override
    {
        // TODO: Implement Caesar cipher decryption
    }
};

class Vigenere : public Cipher
{
public:
    std::string encryption(std::string const& s) override
    {
        // TODO: Implement Vigenere cipher encryption
    }

    std::string decryption(std::string const& s) override
    {
        // TODO: Implement Vigenere cipher decryption
    }
};
```

From this we could create a set of functions to use  any cipher (through pointers to the base `Cipher` class). Lets start with selecting which cipher to use:

```
Cipher* select_cipher()
{
    std::cout << "Please select cipher to use:\n";
    std::cout << "1) Caesar\n";
    std::cout << "2) Vigenere\n";

    int selection;
    std::cin >> selection;

    if (selection == 1)
    {
        return new Caesar;
    }
    else if (selection == 2)
    {
        return new Vigenere;
    }
    else
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Now we have a cipher to use, then select what to do:

```
int select_method()
{
    std::cout << "Do you want to encrypt or decrypt?\n";
    std::cout << "1) Encrypt\n";
    std::cout << "2) Decrypt\n";

    int method;
    std::cin >> method;

    return method;
}
```

Now we really have everything needed to use any supported cipher and method:

```
int main()
{
    Cipher* cipher = select_cipher();
    int method = select_method();

    std::string input;
    std::string result;

    // TODO: Read input string to encrypt or decrypt

    if (method == 1)
    {
        result = cipher->encryption(input);
    }
    else if (method == 2)
    {
        result = cipher->decryption(input);
    }

    std::cout << "Result = " << result << '\n';
}
```

Do note that this is only a very rough outline, and there are many parts missing (like the actual encryption and decryption algorithms). These are left as an exercise for the readers.

Instead of using `if ... else if ...` you can of course use `switch`. But for these simple cases it doesn't really matter, and `if ... else if ...` is, IMO, easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I coded it already can you check it too, please ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Vig {
   public:
      string k;
   Vig(string k) {
      for (int i = 0; i < k.size(); ++i) {
         if (k[i] >= 'A' && k[i] <= 'Z')
            this->k += k[i];
         else if (k[i] >= 'a' && k[i] <= 'z')
            this->k += k[i] + 'A' - 'a';
      }
   }
   string Vegencryption(string t) {
      string output;
      for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < t.length(); ++i) {
         char c = t[i];
         if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            c += 'A' - 'a';
         else if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
            continue;
         output += (c + k[j] - 2 * 'A') % 26 + 'A'; //added 'A' to bring it in range of ASCII alphabet [ 65-90 | A-Z ]
         j = (j + 1) % k.length();
      }
      return output;
   }
   string Vegdecryption(string t) {
      string output;
      for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < t.length(); ++i) {
         char c = t[i];
         if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')
            c += 'A' - 'a';
         else if (c < 'A' || c > 'Z')
            continue;
         output += (c - k[j] + 26) % 26 + 'A';//added 'A' to bring it in range of ASCII alphabet [ 65-90 | A-Z ]
         j = (j + 1) % k.length();
      }
      return output;
   }
   string Cesencryption(string t, int key){
      string output;
      char ch;
      for(int i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; ++i){
                ch = t[i];
                
                if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                    ch = ch + key;
                    
                    if(ch > 'z'){
                        ch = ch - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
                    }
                    
                    t[i] = ch;
                }
                else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                    ch = ch + key;
                    
                    if(ch > 'Z'){
                        ch = ch - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
                    }
                    
                    t[i] = ch;
                }
            }
           output = t;
      return output;
   }
   string Cesdencryption(string t, int key){
      string output;
      char ch;
      for(int i = 0; t[i] != '\0'; ++i){
        ch = t[i];
                if(ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z'){
                    ch = ch - key;
                    
                    if(ch < 'a'){
                        ch = ch + 'z' - 'a' + 1;
                    }
                    
                    t[i] = ch;
                }
                else if(ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z'){
                    ch = ch - key;
                    
                    if(ch > 'a'){
                        ch = ch + 'Z' - 'A' + 1;
                    }
                    
                    t[i] = ch;
                }
            }
           output = t;
      return output;
   }
};
int main() {
    char message[200];
    string key;
   int choice;

    cout << "Pick a Choice from the List:  \n(1)Caesar \n(2)Vigenere \n ";
    cin >> choice;
    if(choice == 2) //Vigenere
    {
        cout << "Pick a Choice from the List:  \n(1)Encryption\n(2)Decryption \n ";
        cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 1) 
            {
                cout << "Key: ";
                cin >> key;
                cin.ignore();
                Vig v(key);
                cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
                cin.getline(message, 200);
                string ori = message;
                string encrypt = v.Vegencryption(ori);
                cout << "Encrypted Message: " << encrypt << endl;

            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
                cout << "Key: ";
                cin >> key;
                cin.ignore();
                Vig v(key);
                cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
                cin.getline(message, 200);
                string ori = message;
                string decrypt = v.Vegdecryption(ori);
                cout << "Decrypted Message: " << decrypt << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You Exit the Program.";
            }
    }
    else if (choice == 1) //Ceaser
    {
         cout << "Pick a Choice from the List:  \n(1)Encryption\n(2)Decryption \n ";
         cin >> choice;
            if (choice == 1)
            {
               int key;
               cout << "Enter a message to encrypt: ";
               cin.ignore();
               cin.getline(message, 200);
               cout << "Enter key: ";
               cin >> key;
               Vig v(message);
               string ori = message;
               string decrypt = v.Cesencryption(ori,key);
               cout << "Decrypted Message: " << decrypt << endl;

            }
            else if (choice == 2)
            {
               int key;
               cout << "Enter a message to dencrypt: ";
               cin.ignore();
               cin.getline(message, 200);
               cout << "Enter key: ";
               cin >> key;
               Vig v(message);
               string ori = message;
               string encryption = v.Cesdencryption(ori,key);
               cout << "Decrypted Message: " << encryption << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "You Exit the Program.";
            }
    }
    else
    {
       cout << "You Exit the Program.";
    }
}
```